# Merge some child values back into the parent multidimensional array

Tags: php, array

This is a wonky PHP function I came up with to merge some select values from child arrays into the original.  It could really use some help simplifying / making it more elegant.

Is there a built-in method I'm overlooking?  `array_push` didn't work for me because the data needed to be flat.

### The problem

What I've got:

```
array(
    array(
         'nice_value' => 'yup',
         'nice_value2' => 'yup again',
         'ono' => array(
              'nice_value3' => 'yup yup yup',
              'bad value' => 'nope'
          )

    ),
    // array with the same format
    [...]

);
```

What I need:

```
array(
    array(
         'nice_value' => 'yup',
         'nice_value2' => 'yup again',
         'nice_value3' => 'yup yup yup'
    ),
    // array with the same format
    [...]

);
```

### The wonky solution

```
// calling in multidimensional array from an api
            $lists = $all_lists['data'];
// keys to merge into the parent array, 'key_to_be' => 'key_that_is'
            $keys_to_merge = array('members' => 'member_count');
// init the function
            $newList = merge_selected_values($lists, $keys_to_merge);


// start writing our function
            function merge_selected_values($list, $keys_to_merge) {
// initialize our return array
            $newList = array();
// start a counter
            $ii = 0;
// begin loop
            foreach($list as $key => $value) {
// get first series of array, this is what we want to merge into
                if (is_array($value)) {
// loop through these values
                   foreach ($value as $kk => $vv) {
// find all arrays that are children of our parent array
                      if (is_array($vv)) {
// loop through these child arrays
                          foreach ($vv as $stats_key => $stats_value) {
// start looping through the keys that we want to merge
                             foreach ($keys_to_merge as $keys => $vals) {
// if the key matches 
                                 if ($stats_key === $vals) {
// create a variable to hold it
                                     ${$vals} = $stats_value;
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                      }
                   }
// start looping through keys to merge again
                   foreach ($keys_to_merge as $keys => $vals) {
// find the keys we merged
                       if (${$vals}) {
// create an array that is the merger, merge to existing array if it .. exists
                           if($newList[$ii]) {
                               $newList[$ii] = array_merge($newList[$ii], array($keys => ${$vals}));
                            }  else {
                              $newList[$ii] = array_merge($value, array($keys => ${$vals})); 
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
              $ii++;
            }
            return $newList;
            }
```

Comment: you can check this solution too: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877656/php-hierarchical-array-parents-and-childs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877656/php-hierarchical-array-parents-and-childs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's the criteria for deciding which keys to keep?

Check out the [array_walk_recursive()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) function. For example, the following matches any element with a key that starts with "nice_value".

```
$array = /*your array example*/;
$filtered = array();
array_walk_recursive($array, function($val, $key) use(&$filtered) {
    if (strpos($key, 'nice_value') === 0) {
        $filtered[$key] = $val;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

#### What's wonky

- The `function` line is at the same indentation level as its body.
- The placement and verbosity of the comments.
- Use of variably-named variables.  Gather the key-value pairs to be merged using an associative array instead.

#### Suggested solution

- Use `array_walk_recursive()` as suggested by @jbarreiros to find the key-value pairs you want.
- Use `array_replace()` (or maybe `array_merge()`) to add those key-value pairs back to the original.